# jquery .val('') not working, leaves a 0 instead of clearing the field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I have a jquery.number textbox with value 0

When I run `$('#txt').val(1);` it becomes `1` (so far so good)

When I run `$('#txt').val('');` it becomes `0` ! Not good, I want to clear it.

`document.getElementById('txt').value = "";` This works, but I'd prefer using jquery...

Anyone has a clue on what might be going on?

Comment: can you show some of your code?

Comment: <input class="form-control" data-controltype="jquery-number" data-decimales="0" data-val="false" data-val-length="El tiempo de trabajo en minutos entre 0 y 9999" data-val-length-max="4" data-val-number="The field Tiempo de trabajo en minutos del cuerpo de bomba must be a number." data-val-required="El campo Tiempo de trabajo es requerido." id="txtConatoDeIncendioTiempoDeTrabajo" name="Bomberos.ConatoDeIncendio.TiempoDeTrabajo" type="text" value="">

This is the generated html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because parsing a non numeric value with jQuery is not allowed on an input `type="number"`

If you really want to use `''` properly better use `type="text"`

**Edit:**

There is a reference about this on [developer.mozilla.org/.../isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

> isNaN('');        // false: the empty string is converted to 0 which
> is not NaN

Some more explaination on [jQuery Allow Numbers and Decimal only in Textbox [numeric]](https://codepedia.info/jquery-allow-numbers-decimal-only-in-textbox-numeric-input)

Comment: It already has type="text" and still have same issue

Comment: in your previous comment you mention this code : `data-controltype="jquery-number" `  ...please check it... and also try your page in different browser(Chrome, Firefox,...) to see the compatibility, the numbers are sometimes tricky :)